# Put route in Express not working - sequelize/postgres

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize put route for an application that tracks the locations of trash dumps (when people dump garbage on the side of the road). The record in question, Item, is the record for an individual site. There are no relationships for the record.

I am trying to run this route. I want it so, IF the user provides different data than what is already on record, the data will be updated. But the route stops half way through. I'm not sure why. Here is the route:

```
// UPDATE ITEM
router.put('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    let data; 
    Item 
        .find({ where: { id: req.params.id}})
        .then(data => {
            console.log(`Here is data: ${data.description}`)
            let newDescription = req.body.description ? req.body.description : data.description; 
            console.log("passed description")
            let newStreet = req.body.street ? req.body.street : data.street;
            console.log("passed street")
            let newCrossStreet = req.body.cross_street ? req.body.cross_street : data.cross_street; 
            console.log("passed cross")
            let newAddress = req.body.address ? req.body.address : data.address;
            console.log("passed address")
            let newCity = req.body.city ? req.body.city : data.city; 
            console.log("passed city")
            let newEmail = req.body.email ? req.body.email : data.email;
            console.log("passed email") 
            let newPhone = req.body.phone ? req.body.phone : data.phone; 
            console.log("passed phone")
            return Item 
                .update({ 
                    description: newDescription, 
                    street: newStreet, 
                    cross_street: newCrossStreet, 
                    address: newAddress, 
                    city: newCity, 
                    email: newEmail, 
                    phone: newPhone
                 }, { where: { id: req.params.id }})
                 .then(item => {
                     res.status(204).json({ item })
                 })
                 .catch(err => {
                     console.error(err)
                     res.status(500).json({ message: 'There was a problem' }); 
                 })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'No record was found' }); 
        }); 
});
```

I have the console.logs there to see where the route stops. Here is the console output:

```
App is listening on port 8080
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "description", "street", "cross_street", "address", "city", "photo_url", "email", "phone", "desired_reply", "completed", "date_reported", "date_completed" FROM "items" AS "Item" WHERE "Item"."id" = '3';
Here is data: Old clothes on the road
::1 - - [16/Apr/2018:22:09:38 +0000] "PUT /item/update/3 HTTP/1.1" 400 33
```

As you can see, it only gets to the very first console.log. Then it seems to stop? I don't know why! Can anyone help me see what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that this line is failing `req.body.description` because `req.body` is not an object

Comment: Yes. Please investigate the existence of body.

Comment: to not only make this more readable, but to help you as well, consider using `debugger` instead of adding a `console.log` after each statement

Comment: Have you installed `body-parser`? Try the following `router.put('/update/:id', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) =>`. See this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132442/8954866

Comment: That's it. I forgot jsonParser. Thank you!